# how can i use tqdm to visualize the progress of training steps using tf.data.Dataset api?

Tags: tensorflow, tqdm

I want to use tqdm to visualize my cnn network training steps.
How can I implement `tqdm` with `tf.data.Dataset()` api?
Can u show me a sample code? thx!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We are more of a code correction service rather than a code writing service. You need to make an attempt to implement this yourself before asking the community. If you are stuck then cite specific documentation related to what is that you do not understand. Also, be sure to spell out your words rather than using mobile-phone-speak abbreviations since this is a professional site not an informal social site. [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Regards!

Comment: ...and then the OP posted his own answer...

Answer (score 2):

*NOTE: although this is an obviously flagged question with mal practise, I still think it is a valid question (I had myself) and post a solution.*

A possibility is to obtain the cardinality of your dataset previously and use it as @mr.melon states in tqdm.

```
cardinality = np.sum([1 for i in dataset.batch(batch_size)])
```

where `dataset` is of class `tf.data.Dataset` and you haven't done the full preparation pipeline (I refere to interleaving, shuffling, batch and prefect and their kind).

Then you can

```
for input, label in tqdm(dataset, total=cardinality):
...
```

Answer (score -2):

It's pretty easy:

1. Derive the number of samples in your dataset,
2. Then, convert the number into some iterable python structure.

   ```
   for _ in tqdm(iterable=xxx, total=num_samples):
        batch_data = sess.run(ele_derived_from_tf_dataset)
   ```